# Serve from file system or remote alternative

Tags: php, apache

Please note, the following is for development purposes so I'm not taking too much concern over security.

Here's the situation:

- Files are served from assets.example.com
- The local development environment attempts to load files from localhost.assets.example.com instead
- We would like to keep localhost.assets.example.com and assets.example.com in sync.

  - There is a lot of data, so holding it all locally is problematic.
  - Replacement or new files need to be served on localhost.assets.example.com without affecting the live assets.example.com

Proposed solution:

- When a request is made to localhost.assets.example.com, serve the file from the local file system if it exists, if it does not exist then look to try to serve the file from assets.example.com should it exist. Else 404.

This has the effect that only changed or new files need to live on the development machine, and deleting all the assets files locally would in effect mirror the live assets.

We're already using PHP 5.3, so that can be used as part of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apache:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) http://assets.example.com/$1 [P]
```

[`[P]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p):

> Use of the [P] flag causes the request to be handled by mod_proxy, and handled via a proxy request.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. When I test for a file that doesn't exist on localhost.assets.example.com but does exist on assets.example.com, I get an empty file downloaded that has type: application/x-trash

Comment: x-trash is only when I rename the local file .old. I'm just getting 404.

Comment: Do you have mod_proxy installed, and what do your apache logs say?

Comment: mod_negotiation was enabled. As soon as I disabled it, the above suggestion began to work.